# How to get the current page URL in the requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm in a loop, navigating paged search results. The next button never disappears. I want to keep clicking it until the URL no longer changes. I imagine I will need a requests session? I want to do something like this:

```
new_url = soup.find("blahblah")['href']
if session.current_url == new_url:
    return
```

Comment: Could you please provide more detailed snipped? How do you open the page? If you just use `requests`, then you have to pass it the url to open, so it seems that you already know it, so why you need to get it from the session? Or do you use some kind of automation libary like `MechanicalSoup`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the response object, there is a `.url` property that you can use to access the URL of the current page.

Comment: Could you give an example of the code used to do that?
I have a similar question.     I'm looping through webpages using splinter, and the webpage where I ultimately end is different from the response object (I think).  Let me give you an example:

browser.visit(url)  -- go to first page

for headline in titles:
    print(headline.text)
    browser.click_link_by_partial_text(headline.text) #This takes me to a new page
    html = requests.get( 'I need the new URL but don't know how to get it')